# Facebook og:tags not working in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, meta-tags

I am trying to add og:tags for sharing my URL on facebook. below is my code
in my view file,

```
- content_for :og_meta_tags do
  %meta{:content => "#{FbAppId}", :property => "fb:app_id"}/
  %meta{:content => "Travelibro blog", :property => "og:name"}   
  %meta{:content => @journey.photos.first.image.url, :property => "og:image"}
  %meta{:content => "website", :property => "og:type"}/
  %meta{:content => user_journey_url, :property => "og:url"}/
  %meta{:content => "Travelibro - #{@journey.name}", :property => "og:title"}/
  %meta{:content => "The TraveLibro app allows your to capture your live journeys On-The-Go with simple check-ins, picture uploads and thoughts to create a beautiful timeline of your travels. It enables friends travelling together to share experiences and post moments to a shared timeline and loved ones to see them in real time.", :property => "og:description"}
```

and my application.html.haml file contains the below code,

```
<!doctype html>
 %html
   %head{:prefix => "og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#"}        
    %link{:href => "http://test.com", :rel => "canonical"}      
    = yield :og_meta_tags
    .
    .
    .
```

but, when I scrape a new information from facebook debugger tool, I get the following errors,

```
a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
```

It's not picking up my og:tags at all.

For example, below is the URL to be share on the facebook :

http://travelibro.com/monish-shah/journeys/bangalore-day-trip-2149

when I put this URL to facebook debugger tool, I get the following error

```
Object at URL 'http://travelibro.com/monish-shah/journeys/bangalore-day-trip-2149' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
```

Comment: Give us an actual example URL, so that we can have a look at the issue.

Comment: Yes, I edited my question